# How to remove question mark from URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Is there any way I can remove the question mark from URL? Now lets say that the URL can be `http://www.domain.com/profile?a=10` but it can also be `http://www.domain.com/profile?b=ticket`.

So in the first case my URL should be `http://www.domain.com/profile/10` and in the second `http://www.domain.com/profile/ticket`.

But I still want to be able to use `$_GET` in `PHP`. So what I really want is to remove the question mark only to the user, but in the server it should work the same. Is there any way I can do this, probably using `htaccess`.  I am running `apache2` as my webserver on Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: What will ```a```and ```b``` look like? Will ```a``` always be a number and ```b``` not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it with `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^profile/([^.]*)$ profile.php?a=$1&b=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

where profile.php will be your PHP code that handles both the cases.