# How to remove "?" Question Mark from URL in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Please help me. how to remove "?" in query string url `rhino/sub-categories/?category=Hotel` like as 'rhino/sub-categories/Hotel' in localhost. it's called data in custom database. So, i want to remove `?` from the url. I'm trying htaccess like as-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>   
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteBase /rhino/   
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]   
RewriteRule ^sub-categories/([^.]*)$ sub-categories/?category=$1 [QSA,L]   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteRule . /rhino/index.php [L]   
</IfModule>
```

and try function.php like as:-

```
function listen_rewrite_action() {   
add_rewrite_tag('%category%','([^/]*)');   
add_rewrite_rule('^sub-categories/([^/]+)$','index.php?pagename=sub-categories&category=$matches[1]','top');  
add_rewrite_rule('^sub-categories/([^/]+)/page/([^/]+)$', 'index.php?pagename=sub-categories&category=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]','top');    
}   
add_action( 'init', 'listen_rewrite_action' );
```

syntax and many more. Please help me how to solve this.

Comment: Can you show us what have you have tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove question mark from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322204/how-to-remove-question-mark-from-url)