# Remove Question Mark on Wordpress URL

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

I want to remove the ? in my URL but dont know how to do that...

Can you please help me?

`http://domain.de/projekte/agbz/?deutschland/zahnarzt/Uta_Blumenstein_Kassel_Z4911334`

its the questionmark after "/agbz/"....

Comment: Search and replace? Why do you need a regex?

Comment: Its a dynamic generated Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need to restore your web files or database. Also no need to workaround related permalinks settings. This issue only related for those who use Plesk control panel only.

Go to your control panel, on “Apache & nginx Settings” section, make sure everything revert back to default.

On “Hosting Settings” section, under “Web scripting and statistics” section take a look PHP version of your website and run PHP as xxxx. Change run PHP as xxx from previous one to another. ie. I have previously FastCGI application serverd by Apache. Now change it to another else, ie. FPM application served by nginx.

Comment: I think this is a replication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322204/how-to-remove-question-mark-from-url